# how can I get the number of directories in a directory?

Tags: c, linux, unix, system

I am trying to get the number of directories in a folder except the files in but I cannot get the correct result. Somebody help me to solve this problem? Especially what should I sent to the isDirectory() function?

```
int listFilesIndir(char *currDir) 
{
    struct dirent *direntp;


    DIR *dirp;
    int x ,y =0 ;


    if ((dirp = opendir(currDir)) == NULL) 
    {
        perror ("Failed to open directory");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
        x= isDirectory(dirp);
        if(x != 0)
            y++;
    }
    printf("direc Num : %d\n",y );

    while ((closedir(dirp) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) ;

    return 0;
}


int isDirectory(char *path) 
{
    struct stat statbuf;

    if (stat(path, &statbuf) == -1)
        return 0;
    else 
        return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}
```

Comment: What do you get instead of the "correct result"?

Comment: Passing "dirp" to isDirectory() seems wrong.  Is that a typo?

Comment: This comment might be utterly unhelpful, but it hurts my eyes to see so many lines of code for a conceptual one-liner... `ls -d <PATH>/*/ | wc -l`

Comment: corrent result means the number of directories. I do not want to count the files but directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a directory stream to the function, and treating it like a path.

Linux and some other Unix systems include a way to get this info directly:

```
while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
    if (direntp->d_type == DT_DIR)
       y++;
}
```

Otherwise, make sure you send the right details to the function, i.e.

```
x= isDirectory(direntp->d_name);
```

Comment: It doesnt work Teppic. I get the number of all files in current directory when I follow your way. Have another way?

Answer (score 1):

The call for your function is wrong.

```
x= isDirectory(dirp);
```

While the prototype of function  is:

```
int isDirectory(char *path)
```

It need a string as parameter, but you give it a "DIR *dirp;". I changed the code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int listFilesIndir(char *currDir)
{
    struct dirent *direntp;


    DIR *dirp;
    int x ,y =0 ;


    if ((dirp = opendir(currDir)) == NULL)
    {
        perror ("Failed to open directory");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name);
        if(direntp->d_type == DT_DIR)
            y++;
    }
    printf("direc Num : %d\n",y );

    while ((closedir(dirp) == -1) && (errno == EINTR)) ;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc == 2){
        // Check whether the argv[1] is a directory firstly.
        listFilesIndir(argv[1]);
    }
    else{
        printf("Usage: %s directory", argv[0]);        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tested it on my Linux server. And it works well. SO @teppic is right. But pay attention, in the code, the number of directory includes two specific ".." (parent directory) and "." (current directory). If you do not want to include it, you could change:

```
printf("direc Num : %d\n",y );
```

into:

```
printf("direc Num : %d\n",y-2 );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thats the point but I cannot find what I should sent to the function. How can I get info about the file?

Comment: If you really need to call the function int isDirectory(char *path), you could do it as: isDirectory(direntp->d_name);

Comment: Ouh of course Teppic is right Shane. I forgot about the curr dir and parent dir  . It really works great.Thanks all for your help..